# Print "Hello World" in Ascii Art ... without its characters

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

Your mission is to write a program that prints "Hello World!". Simple?

The text must be human readable and should not be "|-| € |_ |_ 0  // 0 |? |_ |)  \./" or something like that.

The program should not contain:

- Newline character
- Any characters in the string "Hello World!" including whitespace (whitespace outside strings is allowed)
- Graphics (it must be run on text console (or master boot record in text mode)
- Number constants that represent chars (Ascii-values, Hex chars)
- Any simple tricks that create above numbers (ex. 36*2 or 176/2-1 (72, ASCII code of "H") )
- Non-ASCII chars
- Web request
- User input
- Over 1000 chars
- Random numbers

It can contain:

- Ascii-art
- system calls that do not return letters (a-z and A-Z)
- h, e, l, o, w, r, d and ! chars outside strings or equal datatypes

It is possible and allowed to change line by going over line max width (program must detect that itself). Linux command

```
stty size
```

may help.

Fewer chars are better.

Basically, write 'Hello World' in Ascii Art.

Comment: *"Less chars is better"* -> should this be tagged `code-golf`? And `restricted-source`?

Comment: Edit1: over 1000 chars and random numbers forbidden, because cat /*v/u*and*m and other like this

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica

`n` is an integer (in base 10).

`IntegerDigits[n, 2]` is a list of digits {0,1} that, when concatenated, represent `n` in base 2.

`a=ArrayReshape[ IntegerDigits[n, 2], {19, 130}]` is the same digit list rearranged as a grid of 0's and 1's with the dimensions {19, 130}.

`a/. {1 -> Style["b", 0], 0 -> Style["*", 16]}` replaces each 1 with "b" of font size 0 (hence it is invisible) and replaces each 0 with "*" of font size 16.

`Grid[%, Spacings-> 0]` tightly displays the array, with replacements. (`%` stands for the line of code just preceding.)

```
n = 35001712241657190367892609813472861877431771881809334927846103886350214620897333001318391750688831360911930936377842577561578307677143958805011717980866099960819297494949545473701708671861367649525697579614849813048033148938384921009819295565066663593631828895192249784580492554132824237605034894192899878952441264004931502456152233835512128208573340080592412541607535529943162874085478980356198477815840725568296012406592398594861031009108478191718964371749381682556005188569781665817649936105396104242935885784130227679335972626450197115544027612921177483696531170727698036575934297259107966503600164537149096917592511980213534973597038276657982204662616524347887277731541480128061438343931154467720012975561086600146498015257664764847849471;
Grid[ArrayReshape[ IntegerDigits[n, 2], {19, 130}] /. {1 -> " ", 0 -> Style["*", 16]}, 
   Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `" "` legal? Wondering because of "*...including whitespace...*" in the character restrictions.

Comment: Just to be safe, I replaced spaces with the letter `b` of font size 0.

Comment: This contains an `h`, an `e`, an `l`, ...

Comment: @Doorknob I've found a way to eliminate the `h` and the `l`, but no solution yet for the `e`.

Comment: It still contains an `l` and a `d` as well.

Answer (score 4):

## J - 59 or 84 char

Two versions, depending on how you define 'human-readable'. Any modifications to the resulting ASCII art would ultimately be based on this kind of compression scheme.

```
,.'#'#~"0#:86235578437 123845917517 91625269844 92707043917
,._45#&'#'"0\#:36761300340830444705259651524275206394141032533795647996053048645081x
```

The first version works by taking its list of numbers, expanding them into bitvectors (`#:`), using those to select (`#~`) how many '#' to take for each point (`"0`) in the matrix, and then running the result (a 2D matrix of strings of length at most 1) into a matrix of characters (`,.`).

The second does the same thing, except it's shorter—by one character, mind you!—to pack all of its bitvectors into a single extended precision number, which you then take 45 bit cuts (`_45(blah)\`) of.

Here's what they look like:

[screenshot of jconsole running code http://i.snag.gy/XzYYa.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/XzYYa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + tr, <strike>82</strike> 79 bytes

```
a=({q..s});a=${a[@]};s=${a:1:1};t${a:2:1} "[$s-~]" "[u-~][$s-v]"<<<Tqxx{,c{~xp-
```

Output:

```
$ a=({q..s});a=${a[@]};s=${a:1:1};t${a:2:1} "[$s-~]" "[u-~][$s-v]"<<<Tqxx{,c{~xp-
Hello World!
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java generating the Strings only from a 0 as integer; 391 chars

```java
class A{static int a=0,b=a++,e=a++,f=a/a;static char p(String s){return(char)Byte.parseByte(s,a);}public static void main(String[]z){long x=e,y=b;String c=((Long)x).toString(),d=((Long)y).toString();char l=p(c+c+d+c+c+d+d),m=p(c+c+d+d+c+d+c),o=(char)(l+a+f),_=p(c+d+d+d+d+d),$=_++;System.out.print(new char[]{p(c+d+d+c+d+d+d),m,l,l,o,$,p(c+d+c+d+c+c+c),o,(char)(o+a+f),l,(char)(m-f),_});}}
```

in that code the only literal variable is an Integer 0, the rest is made via Wizardry and other math tricks